# Swift 3 error: "See also" callout not showing

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, code-documentation

I just migrated my project to Swift 3 and found that the "See also" callout in the quick help is not showing. Everything was perfectly working in the previous version of Swift. Below is my code:

```
/**
 Adds a "See also" callout in the Quick Help for a symbol using the `seealso` delimiter. Multiple "See also" callouts appear in the description section in the same order as they do in the markup.

 - author: Tapas Pal

 - remark: Use the callout to add references to other information.

 - seealso: [The Swift Standard Library Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/index.html)
*/
class SeeAlsoMarkup: NSObject {
    static func doSomething() {}
}
```

The output is as follows:

[image]

Did Apple change anything with this markup? Apple's [See Also](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/SeeAlso.html) markup formatting reference is still showing `seealso` as a valid callout.

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: Not yet..... :(

Comment: Seems like a bug, it doesn't display for me and it's been a while since this post. My solution for now is to use something like `**See also:** TextField`

Comment: did you try keeping it case sensitive e.g `- SeeAlso: `

Comment: I think @ShubhamNaik is right. seeAlso works for me.

Comment: @Jevon718 What Xcode version (build) you using? Still not working for me.

Comment: @nemissm 9.3 and it's still working for me

Comment: I'm using Xcode 9.2; neither `- seealso:`, `- seeAlso:` nor `- SeeAlso:` works on option-click. All are highlighted in code as "Documentation Markup Keywords" though.

Comment: `- returns:` for the method's return value doesn't seem to work either (it **is** highlighted as documentation comment keyword in the editor though).

Comment: This is still an issue in Xcode 10.1, all `- seealso:`, `- seeAlso:`, `- SeeAlso:` gets **highlighted** in the comment, but neither works as documentation (when alt-clicking)

Comment: This is still an issue in Xcode 10.2.1 (haven't updated to 11 yet): `- SeeAlso` (and its variations) is written in bold letters in the code but doesn't show up in the documentation popup. @NicolasMiari Try an uppercase `- Returns:`.

Comment: @Neph: still an issue in Xcode 11 beta 4.

Comment: Still an issue in Xcode 11.5.

Comment: Same in Xcode 13rc1. 

Comment: And same in 14.x. It seems this feature has a lot of issues since its first introduction, until now. I hope someone at Apple takes some responsibility. Honestly, it's a cool feature, it just never worked flawlessly.  ;)

Answer (score 8):

(XCode 11, Swift 5)

For clarification on this question, it appears that XCode recognizes markdown in documentation comments. If you have something like:

```
/// # Reference 
/// [Link to Reference](https://www.google.com)
```

It gets recorded as:

[image: Screen shot of Reference markdown]

I don't know that this hooks into the documentation keywords in the same way that `@seealso` does, because the `#` markdown tag just refers to a header style. To demonstrate this point, you can add arbitrary sections to your documentation using the `#` tag:

```
///  # Reference
///  [Link to Reference](https://www.google.com)
///  # Section
///  This is a new section of documentation
///  # Remark
///  New remark
```

Gets recorded as:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Replace `seealso` with `# Reference`.

[image: Quick Help screenshot]

Comment: @Sajjon instead of `- SeeAlso: [Title](link)` use `# Reference \n [Title](link)`

Comment: With  # Reference, Xcode doesn't show the included link

Comment: @KIO, it does, but only if you have a newline after `Reference`.