# Some documentation features not working in Xcode 8

Tags: swift, xcode, documentation, xcode8

I'm experimented with documentation comments for Swift in Xcode 8 and found that not every feature from [Markup Formatting Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/) works. In particular, I can't make [`seealso:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/SeeAlso.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016497-CH45-SW1) callout working and can't [insert image URL](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/Images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016497-CH17-SW1) to my documentation comments.

That's how my `seealso:` looked like:

[image: broken seealso]

I used exactly the same comments as described on these webpages.

Did anybody have the same problem? Does anybody know the solution?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with `seealso` but unfortunately no solution yet.

Comment: Same behavior! Is [this](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1161) the official bug report?

Comment: FWIW, I notice that [Jazzy](https://github.com/realm/jazzy/) does honor `seealso`, even if it doesn't in Xcode's quick help.

Comment: Same here, just checked XCode10 Beta doesn't work there either..

Answer (score 1):

Try to update new Xcode.
in my experiance work well after delete derived data or clean build press shift+command+K

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
# See also
[Link to Google](https://www.google.com)
```

It's been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233672/swift-3-error-see-also-callout-not-showing)